# How can table content resposponsive in bootsrap

Tags: html, html-table, responsive

i am trying to set **th** width but it change only desktop view.
if i open that page in mobile table th not properly set.
i have also try col-xs-2 to fix **th** but it is not work

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="row" >
                                        <div class = "table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr class="info">
                                                        <th class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" > No</th>
                                                        <th class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">Dish Name</th>
                                                        <th class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"> Size</th>
                                                        <th class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">Prize</th>
                                                        <th class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">Order</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr title="Order Chicken Kadhai">
                                        <td >1</td>
                                        <td >Chicken Kadhai</td>
                                        <td >Full</td>
                                        <td >150/-</td>
                                        <td ><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="ORDER"> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>    
                                        <td >2</td>
                                        <td >Chicken Roast</td>
                                        <td >Full</td>
                                        <td >250/-</td>
                                        <td ><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="ORDER"> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td >3</td>
                                        <td >Chicken Tandori</td>
                                        <td >Full</td>
                                        <td >350/-</td>
                                        <td ><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="ORDER"> </td>
                                    </tr> 
                                </tbody>
                            </table>  
                          </div>                                            
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

[image]

how can we set **th** to responsive table

Comment: Thanks its work i forget . before table thats it is not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

write `<class=".table-responsive>"` instead of class=`<class="table-responsive>"`

Comment: This is wrong; the preceding `.` is for CSS selectors. It is not used in HTML classes.

Comment: But if i remove . i will show scroll bar in browser and if i write .table-responsible i will adjust column contains

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> columns are not made for use in tables. [.table-responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive) adjusts
>   itself according to the content.

Answer (score 0):

use this code might be help for you

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: i have not write . thats why it creating a problem
thanks for your asnwer

Comment: if u got the ans please check it.